# Print last completed jobs when opening terminal (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I am currently running several simulations on my Linux machine, but the amount of directories and subdirectories I have for every case has become quite vast so at times is a bit hard to keep track. I would like to know if there is a command I can introduce in my .bashrc so that every time I open a new terminal it would tell me what jobs have been completed from my last login or the last N completed jobs.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared solution for logging in all your jobs. Next you can look for the last log.
Something like

sleepjob.sh

```
outputdir=$HOME/jobs
mkdir -p "${outputdir}" 2>/dev/null
outputfile=${outputdir}/sleepjob.log
sharedlog=${outputdir}/overview.log
echo "$0 started at $(date)" >> "${outputlog}"
sleep 300
echo "$0 finished at $(date) (result $?)" >> "${outputlog}"
# or all finished jobs in a shared log
echo "$0 finished at $(date) (result $?)" >> "${sharedlog}"
```

Start this script with `nohup` and show the files in the `outputdir` from `.bashrc`

```
echo "Last completed job: $(tail -1 $HOME/jobs/overview.log)"
```